# Change existing ASP .NET web application to support multiple time zones

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime, utc

I have an existing web application with 70+ projects; DB: 700+ tables, 500+ stored procedures.
Currently there are many tables with Datetime/Date fields.

When saving date/datetime information in DB, i need to change them to UTC to support multiple time zone (since the application is going to be accessed across many regions - servers can also be hosted on multiple regions; currently it is accessed only from one region)

In order to do this i have come up with the below steps:

1. Get the list of tables with date/datetime field.
2. Check how its date time field is populated (ie. either through the application or through the procedure)
3. List item.
4. convert the datetime to UTC before saving it to DB.
5. When displaying it in the user's browser, convert the time back to the user's timezone.
6. Can write a query to update existing values with UTC.

The problem is the application by itself is very huge and there are too many places (both from the application & procedure) where datetime is updated; Though i can get the list of tables/procedure names through query directly, updating each procedure (in back end) /file (in front end) is a very tedious process

I would like to know the best approach/suggestions (change the application to support multiple timezone with minimal changes) to proceed in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal situation is that all dates are UTC, in the stored procedures, in process code, in API interfaces etc.

The only time it should not be UTC is directly before it is rendered for a human user

As you indicate a web application, this should be isolatable to just the HTML rendering areas, and this should be the only code you need to change after you switch the DB to UTC

You should just need two function changes:

1. Decode human input into a valid date and convert into UTC from that sessions time zone (do this before any other processing logic)
2. Convert date value from UTC to current sessions time zone, and format into human readable form (do this just before displaying date)

These two functions should already exist in your UI code for date formatting and validation, they just need tweeking

Comment: He is already well aware of how it SHOULD be.  His question is asking how he can make this happen in his very large and complex app without doing it all manually.

Comment: No, you are telling him how it SHOULD be designed.  You have not addressed the fact that he has hundreds of stored procedures that hardcode current (locale specific) time entries (ie GETDATE()), nor that he tons of code that probably does `DateTime.Now`.  Changing just those things won't do anything for him for all of his current code.  Who cares which pronoun is used?

Comment: He says "The problem is the application by itself is very huge and there are too many places (both from the application & procedure) where datetime is updated", this indicates his stored procedures are specifically setting the time (ie GETDATE()), and he has much code that specifically sets the time (ie most likely DatetTime.Now).  Just because he didn't say them specifically doesn't mean you should assume they don't exist.

Comment: As for "simple to implement", it's not.. "their" entire question is based on the fact "they" didn't want to have to manually update all "their" code in hundreds of places where dates are currently being hard coded.  You provided no suggestion how to address this problem which was the primary purpose of "their" question, and you ignored it entirely.  Instead, you suggested the problem didn't exist, and that they should just look harder at "their" code for two places to change.  Which, frankly, telling them their problem doesn't exist is a lot more insulting than referring to them as "he"

Comment: I don't have an answer, because what they want is impossible (to fix all their code without manually fixing all their code)

Comment: That's like saying "Building the great wall of china isn't so bad, so long as you build the wall first".  It's that part you are brushing over that is the meat of the problem.

Comment: I have +1-ed this answer because i would have answered something similar. Also, the 6 comments above me have a good point that you can only do this by really deeply scrutinizing your code (why they are 6 comments and not 1 is beyond my comprehension). One pitfall can also be that you might think your changes are successful when in fact they might not be, so hopefully your code is thoroughly tested. My approach to such a problem would be to force a rewrite of the code by completely removing the Datetime/Date fields (or renaming them) (see next comment...

Comment: ... that will automatically show you the places where your app breaks and needs to be changed (if thoroughly tested or if there's some form of type safety in your code) e.g. you could just use a number to store the time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch. This can very nicely be interpreted in whatever client device/programming language you are using. So i would write a layer which forces others methods to call this layer when dealing with time stuff so that you have more control of database changes in the future.

Comment: @Teo Yes, for business purposes and especially reporting, having you own date class is usually better than using the built in dates, which are a one size fit's all

Answer (score -1):

It's too late for you, but when designing an application which puts a datestamp on any record changes, the correct thing to do is to write a SQL trigger that sets the date appropriately.